# Windsor, inject container in class

Tags: castle-windsor

Hi have the following component registered into Castle Windsor:

```
public class CommandDispatcher : IServiceCommandDispatcher
{
    private readonly IWindsorContainer container;

    public CommandDispatcher(IWindsorContainer container)
    {
        this.container = container;
    }

    #region IServiceCommandDispatcher Members

    public void Dispatch<TCommand>(TCommand command) where TCommand : IServiceCommand
    {
        var handler = container.Resolve<IServiceCommandHandler<TCommand>>();
        handler.Handle(command);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

And the dispatcher is registered in the following way:

```
Component
   .For<IServiceCommandDispatcher>()
   .ImplementedBy<CommandDispatcher>(),
```

But the field **container** is null when I resolve an instance of the dispatcher.
What should I do in order to pass the container to the resolved children items?

Comment: I found this:
container.Register(Component.For<IWindsorContainer>().Instance(contaienr)); to work properly.

Comment: Windsor doesn't do it for a reason.

Comment: Well, I don't think your answer will be helpful to anybody ... What is the reason? Should I inject 100 different command handlers? What's your solution?

Comment: Take a step back and do some reading about philosophy behind containeres, what they're actually for. FAQ might be not a bad place to start: http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.FAQ.ashx?NoRedirect=1&NS=Windsor#Why_wont_Windsor_inject_itself__IWindsorContainer__into_my_components_8

Comment: Usually (but not always), calling container.Resolve directly is a code smell.  It means there's probably a better way to do what you want *without* having to use the container directly.

Comment: I apply SOLID everywhere in my code, but a command dispatcher should be able to resolve any command handler only when it is required, so injecting all of them it looks silly, that's why I need to resolve object from the "low level module".
It smells bad but I can't figure out a clean way right now, any suggestion?

Comment: Have you actually read the FAQ?

Answer (score 3):

Windsor solves this problem for you with the [Typed Factory Facility](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/typed-factory-facility.md).

In the below example I want the implementation of `ICommandHandlerFactory` to resolve my command handler from my windsor container.

```
class CommandDispatcher : IServiceCommandDispatcher
{
    private readonly ICommandHandlerFactory factory;

    public CommandDispatcher(ICommandHandlerFactory factory)
    {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    public void Dispatch<T>(T command) where T : IServiceCommand
    {
        var handler = this.factory.Create(command);
        handler.Handle(command);
        this.factory.Destroy(handler);
    }
}
```

To achieve this I only need to create the `ICommandHandlerFactory` Interface.

```
public interface ICommandHandlerFactory
{
    Handles<T> Create<T>(T command) where T : IServiceCommand;
    void Destroy(object handler);
}
```

No implementation of `ICommandHandlerFactory` is required as Windsor will create the implementation. Windsor uses the convention that a method that returns an object is a `resolve` method and a method that returns void is a `release` method.

To register the factory you need to include `using Castle.Facilities.TypedFactory` and then register your factory as follows

```
container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();

container.Register(
     Component.For<ICommandHandlerFactory>()
         .AsFactory()
);
```

Just to reiterate **you do not have to write any implementation code** for your factory.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
container.Register(Component.For<IWindsorContainer>().Instance(container));
```

It's not ideal, because you still have to call the *Resolve* method.  There may be a better way to do this, using a factory.  This looks similar to what you're trying to do:

http://kozmic.net/2010/03/11/advanced-castle-windsor-ndash-generic-typed-factories-auto-release-and-more/